# Restart the apache service on a server based on the varnish health status

Tags: ansible

I have 3 instances running on centos 7
1. Ansible Server
2. Varnish Server
3. Apache httpd server
I want to restart the apache service  when varnish service is up but varnish health status showing ""Sick" because apache service is stopped.

I have already created a playbook and defined the both hosts but not working

```
- name: Check Backend Nodes
  shell: varnishadm backend.list | awk 'FNR==2{ print $4  }'
  register: status1

- name: print backend status
  debug:
    msg: "{{status1.stdout_lines}}"


 #tasks:
- include_tasks: /etc/ansible/apache/tasks/main.yml
  when: status1.stdout_lines == 'Sick'
```

Comment: Could you please define "not working"? Is the `when` always skipping? Is the server not restarting? Else?

Comment: Not working means after checking varnish it is always going to apache server and checking the apache status,but i want that if varnish status is healthy it should not go to apache server and if varnish server status is sick then it should go to the apache server and start or restart the httpd service on apache server.

Comment: Great, giving us the output of your `debug` task would have greatly helped. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your `when` condition has a glitch, as you can see in the documentation, [`stdout_lines` is always a list of string](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout-lines), when your condition do compare it to a string.

So your fix could actually be as simple as checking if the string `Sick` is among the list `stdout_lines`:

```
- include_tasks: /etc/ansible/apache/tasks/main.yml
  when: “'Sick' in status1.stdout_lines”
```

Comment: Now getting below error
This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote. For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"

Comment: Indeed, that’s a YAML parsing issue, sorry, the edited code should do

Comment: my varnish task file is : /etc/ansible/varnish/tasks/main.yml
apache task file is : /etc/ansible/roles/apache/tasks/main.yml

main yml file which i am running with ansible-playbook command is : /etc/ansible/varnish.yaml
apache and varnish running on different servers.